# Understanding Spark terminal output during stages

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and am trying to understand the log output of its stages on my terminal. I'm working with a very large data set on my local machine and during actions, I'll see something like:

```
[Stage: 4 ==>           (10 + 4) / 200]
```

I understand that stages are all the operations that happen to the RDD, but what about the numbers at the end? Do they represent tasks?

```
(10 + 4) / 200]
```

- `10` the number of tasks completed?
- `4` the number of concurrent tasks running (ie the number of cores on my machine?)
- `200` the total number of tasks for this stage?

Comment: Looks like you figured out everything by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for verifying! :)

Answer (score 9):

It's called a Console Progress Bar. For the mentioned stage, here's what the numbers mean,

```
[(numCompletedTasks + numActiveTasks) / totalNumOfTasksInThisStage]
```

Hope this helps, Cheers.